# OpenGL ES 2.0 | GUI screen on top of game screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es, controls, opengl-es-2.0

Ok so I want to make a game with openGL ES 2.0, but I have a problem with the controls. until now i made the controls just like any other sprite in my game, just draw it, and if the camera updates, the controls will update after it like "move" with the camera.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Here is an example of what i want to do:

*Game Screen

[image: Game Screen (OpenGL ES 2.0)]

*controls

[image: Game Controls]

And then like lay the controls on top of the Game Screen so it would not move even if the camera moves. Is it possible? maybe mix xml? if so then how? Thanks!

Comment: When you draw the GUI element sprites just use another camera, which never moves. You must also make sure that your GUI elements not accidentally get hidden behind the dynamic scene contents. This can be done by disabling depth testing or modifying glDepthRangef when drawing the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

When you draw the same thing in the same place every frame, it feels like needless work, but on the other hand, every pixel of the screen probably redraws every frame.  Most games don't go to great lengths to avoid this extra work.  I recommend instead trying to win performance by avoiding drawing invisible pixels as much as you can, such as:

- Shrink-wrap the geometry around the UI, so you're drawing as few pixels with alpha 0 as possible.  This might involve drawing more triangles, but in my experience that tradeoff is well worth it.
- Make the depth test work for you.  If your UI is completely opaque, all you have to do is draw it first, and then draw the rest of the scene in the background so that pixels don't draw if they're occluded by the UI.  If your UI is only partly opaque, you could try to subdivide it into opaque triangles and translucent triangles, and draw the translucent ones in separate call at the end so that you can use the depth test on the opaque ones.

Answer (score 0):

I never developed with `OpenGL` but if you are developing it within a certain layout. then what you can do is the following:

1. Place your game layout inside of a `FrameLayout`.
2. Place a `Linearlayout` or `RelativeLayout` inside the same `FrameLayout`.
3. Place your controls in the layout you added.

This way the control you will add will appear on top of the game, You can make the layout semi-transparent for better user experience.